# My image is done loading, but its height and width have not yet been updated. When does this happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, image-loading

I'm using a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BatchImagesLoad) that invokes a callback once all images on page have been loaded.  It checks the `imageObject.complete` property and binds a handler to the `load` and `error` events to determine when image loading is done.

This works well, but the problem I'm running into is that, even though an image is considered loaded, when I inspect the `height` and `width` properties of the image or its containing `div` element, the dimensions have not yet been updated.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RtnVx/12/

How can I ensure that the containing element has been resized to fit the image *before* attempting to access its `height` and `width` dimensions?

**EDIT 1:** I cleaned up and commented the code in my jsfiddle to make the example easier to understand.

**EDIT 2:** There must be a race condition or variation based on caching because when I run the code from a different machine, it works properly (i.e., the top margin is calculated properly), which is actually **not good** because it is not consistent.  The inconsistencies are more apparent in Chrome, FWIW.

Also, to be clear, the goal isn't to call `init` every time an image loads; rather, `init` should be called *once* after all images have been loaded via the AJAX `load` invocation.

Comment: Cleaned up the code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/RtnVx/7/

Comment: Updated answer to handle multiple images, as well as handle error states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/RtnVx/30/**

<strike>You needed to not call `batchImageLoad` until the image was done loading.  I created an event on the loaded image.</strike>

**Updated Notes:**

- **I cut out your jQuery plug-in.** It was overly complex and I didn't completely understand it.
- My current solution **provides error handling** by using the `error` event, as did the plug-in.
- **The solution process:**

  - Find all the `img`'s descending from `#slides` and store that length in a `.data()` attribute, as well as a variable to keep how many have loaded.
  - Bind a `load` and `error` events on each `img` which updates the count of loaded images.
  - If the count of loaded/errored images hits the total image count, call `setTimeout()` until all of them have widths greater than zero then fire `init()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  But `batchImageLoad` doesn't call back to `init` until all of the images are done loading, so it shouldn't matter when I call it, right?  Also, your code will call `init` for *every* image.  I want to call `init` *once* after all images are loaded. (I realize my example only has one image.)

Comment: @Levin Thanks for the update. Your jsfiddle gives me a 404 page, though.  The plugin also binds `load` and `error` to all image elements and also checks for `image.complete` in case an image is in cache (in which case `load` won't fire).  The crux of the issue is that even though an image is loaded, its `height` and `width` properties won't necessarily have updated yet.  This behavior is especially inconsistent in Chrome, I find.  I think we figured out how to wait for all images to load.  Now we have to figure out how to hook into the height & width being set.

Comment: @Rob Jsfiddle has been having problems with that, recently.  Try the updated link now.

Comment: @Levi jsfiddle is back up.  Your code is nice and simple and accomplishes what the `batchImageLoad` plugin does, but is still running into the issue that, even though the images are done loading, their dimensions haven't been updated.

Comment: @Rob You want to use `centerSlides()` after images are loaded, but they are not always resized in time and `centerSlides()` therefore works incorrectly.  Correct?

Comment: @Levi That's correct.  As a solution, I think I'm going to have to call `setTimeout` in the `load` event handler to check if `height > 0`.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Rob Don't disregard this quite yet.  I think I may have a very elegant solution.  I'm not quite sure if it will work at the moment, but I'll let you know.

Comment: @Rob try out the latest solution.

Comment: @Levi Thanks for all your work on this.  It's been fun!  Calling `setTimeout` until the heights/widths are set does the trick.  I wish we had an "dimensions updated" event to hook into, but this will do.